# passing values to a function does not work when inside for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm mapping currencies from a json file and i render the mapped currencies to a component. I have a .php file like this

```
<div class="currency-switch-container" id="currency_container">
    <span style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold">All currencies</span>
    <div id="currency-map" style="margin-top:15px"></div>
</div>
```

I refer the div in the above component in my js file as follows

```
let currencyMap = jQuery("#currency-map");
```

And when my jQuery document is ready i'm doing the following

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $.getJSON('wp-content/themes/mundana/currency/currency.json', function(data) {
    for(let c in data){
      currencyMap.append(`<span onclick="onCurrencyClick(${data[c].abbreviation})"
      class="currency-item">
        <span>
           ${data[c].symbol}
        </span>
        <span>
          ${data[c].currency}
        </span>
      </span>`)
    }
});

}
```

and my function is like this

```
function onCurrencyClick(val){
  console.log("val",val);
  setCookie("booking_currency", val, 14);
}
```

Here the function does not work. But if i do not pass anything to the function it seems to work as i can see the log in the terminal.

Comment: What's the value of `data[c].abbreviation`? I'm guessing it's a string and you need to wrap it in quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi your expression ${data[c].abbreviation} will put the value into function string without string quotes i.e. the resultant would be `onCurrencyClick(abbreviation)` while it should be `onCurrencyClick('abbreviation')`.
please use onclick="onCurrencyClick('${data[c].abbreviation}')" instead.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the inline `onclick`, use *event delegation*. This means that you have a single event listener that handles all the events from the children and grandchildren. The modification is a very minor one seeing the example here below.

A reason for doing this is that you keep your JavaScript inside your JS file. Like now, you encounter a JS error and have to look for it in your HTML. That can get very confusing. Also however inline `onclick` listeners are valid, they are outdated and should be avoided unless there is absolutely no other way. Compare it with using `!important` in CSS, same goes for that.

```
function onCurrencyClick(event){
  var val = $(this).val();
  setCookie("booking_currency", val, 14);
}

currencyMap.on('click', '.currency-item', onCurrencyClick);
```

This example takes the `val` that you try to insert from the `value` attribute from the clicked `.current-item`. `<span>` elements don't have such an attribute, but a `<button>` does and is a much more suitable element for it expects to be interacted with. It is generally a good practice to use clickable elements for purposes such as clicking.

In the example below you see the button being used and the `abbreviation` value being output in the `value` attribute of the `<button>` element and can be read from the `onCurrencyClick` function.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $.getJSON('wp-content/themes/mundana/currency/currency.json', function(data) {
    for(let c in data){
      currencyMap.append(`
        <button value="${data[c].abbreviation}" class="currency-item">
          <span>
            ${data[c].symbol}
          </span>
          <span>
            ${data[c].currency}
          </span>
        </button>
      `)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` will not work for a dynamically added div tag

Yo should follow jQuery `on` event

Refer: [jQuery on](https://api.jquery.com/on/)
Stackoverflow Refer: [Dynamic HTML Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/how-do-i-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements-with-jquery)